# UFW: Allow 2 external IPs + loopback, deny everything else

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, ufw

I have a ubuntu server with IPv4 and IPv6 networking enabled. Currently, network config looks like this:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 45.***.***.**1/24
    gateway 45.***.***.***

# This is an IPv6 interface
iface eth0 inet6 auto
    up   ip addr add 192.168.***.**1/17 dev eth0 label eth0:1
    down ip addr del 192.168.***.**1/17 dev eth0 label eth0:1
```

I want another server in the network, which has the IPs

```
45.***.***.**2  and
192.168.***.**2
```

to be able to access any port, in or out of this server on it's private IP. Traffic in or out from this server's public IP (`45...`) should be dropped. Loopback should of course remain untouched.

Currently there are no IP tables entries or ufw rules. I'd like to go with ufw for it's simplicity. How can I lock down this server as described above?

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you mean by the server's private IP vs. its public IP vs. its IPv6 address?  You have an RFC1918 private IPv4 address indicated on a configuration line which identifies as an IPv6 address which is a virtual IP on a physical device attached to the public internet.  Which leaves me very confused about your desired toplology.

Comment: @quadruplebucky That's true. This is why I can trivially detach the public IP (net 45...). I need to firewall that one off. The goal might be summarized as private network emulation.